# Transfer function of an H bridge circuit

Tags: control-system, motordriver

Hey guys I'm trying to find the transfer function of the given circuit. It is an H bridge motor driver circuit. I have tried to find a spice model for these chips but could not find anything. Any help related would be really appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can H-bridges even have transfer functions? They are non-linear circuits.

Comment: @DKNguyen Sure. They are **H** bridges after all. The transfer function is ***always*** \$H_s\$ for an H-bridge. ;)

Comment: A transfer function implies a stimulus and a response. For a converter, we talk about the control-to-output transfer function which is the relationship linking the control input - usually the duty ratio \$D\$ - with the controlled variable, usually \$V_{out}\$. What transfer function do you refer to here? The current in the motor winding connected to pins 1-3 to the control input on pin 15?

Comment: Are you looking for a transfer function, or a SPICE model? It's not quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified SPICE "circuit" for a IDEAL "bridge" model.
E1 & E2 are the driving "functions".
Bridge has "direction" and "enable" functions (PWM driven).

Can be modified to include some "defects" ...

[image]

Here another circuit with "analog" inputs (based on a sawtooth wave -> PWM).

[image]